# mouse scroll event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two TextBoxs I want to do following :

When I scroll the mouse in one text box then It will be scrolled to same position in the second one , and vice versa .

Thanks for help .

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer , how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will show you how to bind your scrollbars together:

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/18/wpf-elements-how-to-build-a-multi-scheduler/

Basically, you would add the following code to your Value of your scrollbar:

```
Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=YourOtherScrollBar}"
```